# Physical Back button Closing whole application

Tags: flutter, navigation, back-button, flutter-getx

Expected Result:

- Navigate to Previous page

Actual Result

- Closing whole application

To Reproduce :

Wrap that page's Scaffold in a WillPopScope widget

```
return new WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () async {
    return true;
  },
  child: new Scaffold(
    …
  ),
);
```

GetX Version

```
get: ^5.0.0-beta.52

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.0, on Ubuntu 21.04 5.11.0-49-generic, locale en_IN)
• Flutter version 3.3.0 on channel stable at /home/pradeep/snap/flutter/common/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision ffccd96b62 (8 days ago), 2022-08-29 17:28:57 -0700
• Engine revision 5e9e0e0aa8
• Dart version 2.18.0
• DevTools version 2.15.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0-rc1)
• Android SDK at /home/pradeep/Android/Sdk
• Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.0-rc1
• Java binary at: /snap/android-studio/123/android-studio/jre/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at google-chrome

[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
• clang version 6.0.0-1ubuntu2 (tags/RELEASE_600/final)
• cmake version 3.10.2
• ninja version 1.8.2
• pkg-config version 0.29.1

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
• Android Studio at /snap/android-studio/123/android-studio
• Flutter plugin version 70.0.2
• Dart plugin version 212.5744
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
• All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

Comment: are you having this issue in first page of your app?

Comment: yes and it also applies for every page in whole application @eamirho3ein

Comment: are you using Navigator.pushReplacement to navigate to those pages?

Comment: No,I am using Get.toNamed();